# How to taken value in event rowEditing of gridview on asp.net

Tags: asp.net

**Code**

```
 protected void grv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
         string name = (grv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    }
```

or string name **grv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();** //Not work.

Comment: Please show me your .aspx code

Comment: You should format your code for readability and explain how it fails.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to databind the GridView again to be able to **access the control** in the **EditItemTemplate**. So try this:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; 
GridView1.DataSource = somedatasource; //Bind Grid Than Find Control 
GridView1.DataBind();

Textbox txt= GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("textboxid") as TextBox;
 string name = txt.TEXT
```

Comment: but : An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: **code**grv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            grv.DataSource = da.GetTable(); //Bind Grid Than Find Control 
            grv.DataBind();
            TextBox txt = grv.Rows[grv.EditIndex].FindControl("Id") as TextBox;
            string id = txt.Text;**Error in string Name = txt.text; An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Webtest1.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. PLS :(

Answer (score 1):

OnRow Editing,

```
protected void grv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
grv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
grv.DataBind();

 //Find Controls Here like below:
 Textbox txt= grv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("YourTextBoxID") as TextBox;
 DropDownList ddl_branch = (DropDownList)grv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddl_branch");
Label lb_ = (Label)grv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("YourLabelID");
 }
```